# Необходимость в тире

Tags: пунктуация

Понятие "раб" может означать, что человек раб своих желаний.

Обязательно ли тире, можно его опустить?

Answer (score 1):

Тире не обязательно. Этому способствует то, что перед тире лишь одно слово (без зависимых слов и определений).

Тире ставится, если логическое ударение делается на слове "человек". Тогда и присутствует пауза.

Факторы отсутствия тире и ударения:
1) если про слово "человек" говорилось ранее;
2) если говорится про конкретного человека.

Если говорится про всех людей, то тире желательно, так как при обобщении обычно делается пауза. Но это нестандартный случай. Здесь на первом месте слово "раб", а придаточное предложение даётся ради примера с данным словом. Подчёркивать логически слово "человек" (и ставить тире) особо незачем, так как оно играет второстепенную роль.

Comment: oleedd, вы ведь очень любите правила, в частности Розенталя. И при этом вы разрешаете не ставить тире, где по правилам оно должно стоять обязательно, кроме одного исключения. Но это исключение  возможно только при инверсии подлежащего и сказуемого, а тогда меняется смысл сказанного. А вот что означает всё остальное, что вы говорите, я вообще не понимаю. Это уж точно не Розенталь.

Comment: Обязательно стоять должно, если есть ударение. Но при одном слове возможны варианты. А если пауза не задумывается? При отсутствии тире ударения на "желаний". Сравнить: *Человек с деньгАми - раб своих желАний.*

Comment: Оно даже на примеры Рознталя похоже. Стиль у нас разговорный. *Мой брат школьник. Человек раб своих желаний.* Обратите внимание на важный момент - один из элементов является одним словом.

Comment: Ничего не меняем. Стиль книжный.  Отсутствие тире возможно только при инверсии (по Розенталю), но тогда меняется смысл. Пожалуйста, дайте короткий ответ. Это так, да или нет?

Comment: Какой книжный? В словарях нет таких значений этого слова. Здесь не понятие означает, а дан пример с употреблением данного слова. Предложение условное.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение.

Comment: @Sharon Спасибо за то, что поспособствовали тому, что галочку забрали. Мой ответ корректный, интонационный. Планировал дойти до 4000.

Comment: Да пожалуйста, осознаю свою вину. Я вам возмещу моральный ущерб.  Знаете, я когда-то планировала дойти до 1000, мне это представлялось совершенно невозможным. А комментарии я все удалю, чтобы вас не расстраивать. Будьте с нам, oleedd,  и не обижайтесь на дружескую критику.

Comment: Вам такой совет: если что-то непонятно, указывайте на это конкретно. Я же это всё не от фонаря беру. Розенталь формулировал эти исключения на основе наблюдений за реальной речью. Почему бы продвинутым людям (в общем) не сделать какие-то наблюдения, руководствуясь целесообразностью логических ударений и тем, как говорят люди. Разве можно воспринимать правила Розенталя как абсолютно всё, что может существовать в языке? Что-то может быть просто похожим на исключения. Здесь нестандартный разговорный случай, у которого не было шансов попасть в правила.

Answer (score 1):

***Понятие "раб" может означать, что человек – раб своих желаний.***

Можно ли не ставить тире? Изменится ли при этом смысл  предложения? На эти вопросы можно ответить с помощью **интонационно-грамматического анализа**.

Перед нами сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП). Что  интересного в этой грамматической структуре?

1) Сравним: ***Понятие "раб" может означАть,// что человек является рабом своих желАний*.** Вот это классика: две фонетические фразы, разделенные паузой, тоническое ударение в конце каждой фразы.

2) Пропущенная связка и постановка тире в эту ясность **вносят "замутнение".** Сколько теперь-то фраз, неужели три? Да нет, их по-прежнему две, но теперь **основная** пауза **смещена**, она делается между подлежащим и сказуемым в придаточном предложении, там и проходит раздел между двумя фразами (а перед союзом ЧТО – только произносительная пауза): ***Понятие "раб" может означать, что человЕк //– раб своих желАний.*** Вполне известное суждение.

3) А если тире не ставить, то как прочитать предложение? Здесь возможны варианты.

Можно логическим ударением выделить слово "раб": ***Понятие "раб" может означать, //что человек рАб своих желаний.*** Но такое оформление не по правилам: если нет инверсии, то надо ставить тире.

4) Но ударение может падать и на слово *человек*?  **Понятие "раб" может означать, что человЕк / раб своих желАний.** Этот вариант с инверсией разрешен правилами.

Здесь **пауза не подчеркивается**,  она обозначает перелом интонации, как в простом предложении. Тогда  смысл изменится: **Раб своих желаний – это человек.** Автор это хотел сказать? Если уж поискать рабов своих желаний, то им, конечно же, окажется человек?

5) Вариант с инверсией  обозначен у Розенталя: сказуемое и подлежащее меняются местами: *человек* будет сказуемым, а *раб* подлежащим.

Розенталь: Тире не ставится: 6) если сказуемое предшествует подлежащему: Прекрасный человек Иван Иванович! (Г.); Славное место эта долина! (Л.); Живописный народ индийцы (Гонч.); Неплохой ученик этот мальчик.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92

6) Вот такие серьезные изменения в содержание суждения вносит **маленькая черточка, которая называется тире.** Та самая, которую можно то ли ставить, то ли нет.

Comment: Спасибо. Один вопрос. В варианте "человек является рабом своих желаний" можно сделать основное ударение на слове раб: "...что человек **раб** своих желаний". Необходимо ли здесь тире?

Comment: Да, можно. Такое смещенное ударение как раз и называется логическим. Но здесь  варианты уже выбирает читатель.

Comment: Вообще ударение предполагалось на "желаний" : Понятие "раб" может означать, что человек раб своих желАний. Перед этим предложениям осмысливались другие объекты, властвующие над человеком (другие люди, система), а здесь - желАния. Тире в данном предложении будет наводить на мысль, как будто ранее другие властвующие лица вовсе не объяснялись, а значение имеет только данное определение раба. Поэтому вопрос и возник.

Comment: Вот, всё-таки это подпадает под факторы: про слово "человек" говорилось ранее. Например: *Он - герой. Он тот, кто спас нас. Он защитник, который отбил врага.* Повтор ударения на подлежащем удачным назвать нельзя, так как новым оно уже не является.

Comment: Да, этот повтор словно "знакомит" читателя с ним. Это нелепо.

Comment: Вот народный пример (чем-то похожий на этот), демонстрирующий отсутствие тире из-за того, что на подлежащем нет ударения: *На безрыбье и рак рыба.* Где у Розенталя такое правило? Нет всеобъемлющего правила. Есть рекомендации, когда тире часто не ставится.